# Getting Text from Textview in Listview inflated Layout

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in which I inflate a layout with multiple textviews and buttons. I understand to get the text from a view that was clicked is `((Textview)view...`. However I am trying to get the text from the specific textview that is located in the layout in which the user clicked. I have tried using OnItemClick but when I use this the item must be focused before the any of the buttons functions work. I resorted to and prefer using onClickListeners in the `getView` method of my custom adapter. So simply put, how do I click a Button and get the text that is in TextView that is located in the appropriate inflated layout list view item, given that since each inflated layout is considered as one list item?

***UPDATE***

Here are pictures to clarify what i am looking for. Both layouts are members of a listview. [image]

[image]

I want to click the button with the date on it and get the text from the textview in the middle of the layout. However when I click the button with the date on it, I can only get the text from the textview in the middle of the layout of the last child. If "My Party" is the first child in the listview and "3303 going away service..." is the second child, when I click the date button the code in my custom adapter returns the text from the last loaded text in the view which will be "3303 going away service". What I am trying to do is when I click the date button on "My party", get the text "My party". Like wise with the second child.

Here is the getView() in my custom adapter.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        positionHolder = position;
        Log.i("Position", "" + position);

        if(convertView == null) {

            try {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
                postLayout = convertView;

                viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                viewHolder.unameTV.setText(viewContent.get(index));
                viewHolder.unameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Starting new intent
                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Profile.class);
                        // sending pid to next activity
                        String username =((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                        in.putExtra("username", username);

                        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.fillSpace = (TextView)postLayout.findViewById(R.id.posthelpSpace);
                viewHolder.fillSpace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        viewHolder.unameTV.performClick();
                    }
                });




                viewHolder.image = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postProfPic);
                DisplayImageOptions options = initiateDisplayImageOptions();
                viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        viewHolder.unameTV.performClick();
                    }
                });

                ImageLoader imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                initImageLoader(getActivity());
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 1), viewHolder.image, options);




                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarButton);
                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setText(viewContent.get(index + 2));
                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                        cal.setTime(new Date());
                        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
                        long time = cal.getTime().getTime();

                        Uri.Builder builder =
                                CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
                        builder.appendPath("time");
                        builder.appendPath(Long.toString(time));
                        Intent intent =
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);

                        title = testText.getText().toString();
                        Log.i("Title", "" + title);
                        intent.putExtra("title", title); // **NOT WORKING**
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });



                viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                viewHolder.eventTitle.setText(viewContent.get(index + 3));
                viewHolder.eventTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        title = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                        Log.i("TITLE", "" + title);

                    }
                });

                testText = viewHolder.eventTitle;
                viewHolder.eventImage = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 4), viewHolder.eventImage, options);


                viewHolder.likesTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.likesTV);
                viewHolder.likesTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 5));

                viewHolder.planToAttendTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.planToAttendTV);
                viewHolder.planToAttendTV.setText(viewContent.get(index + 6));

                viewHolder.addressTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postLocationTV);
                viewHolder.addressTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 7));


                index = index + 8;


            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) postLayout.getTag();
        }




        return postLayout;
    }
```

Comment: post some code adapter and main

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Specifically what would you like me to post? Only what relates to my problem or are you insinuating that it could be somewhere else? My main contains much code so thats why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom baseadapter and set on click listener for text view in the adapter. This will then be set for the specific text view corresponding to the position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have custom BaseAdapter created, in the custom BaseAdapter setOnclicklistener of the textview to which you want the click to be registered.

**Sample Code Below**

```
public class M_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private TextView contact_name;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> list;
    private List<String> temp;
    private Button btn;

    public M_Adapter(Context context) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        try {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            //add some values in list here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_listrow, parent, false);
        contact_name = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.excl_ppl_contact_name);
        btn=(Button)rowview.findViewById(R.id.excl_ppl_btn);
        contact_name.setText(list.get(temp));

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("myapp", "text clicked " + contact_name.getText());
            }
        });
        return rowview;
    }

}
```

Comment: This isnt exactly what I am trying to achieve I have updated question

Comment: This will only return the text of the last loaded string loaded to the textview, not the row specific text that is in that textview.

Comment: Not understanding your question then..you need to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with two series of if/else statements. First, in my onBindViewHolder (your getView) I have some global String variables take on the value of the TextView I'm interested in. Second, in the onClick method, I have the ViewHolder tell me the position of the item clicked using the getPosition method. Last, I match the value of the position clicked with the String variables created in the first part and carry on from there.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        YelpAPI.businessNumber = position;
        YelpAPI.queryAPI(YelpAPI.yelpApi, YelpAPI.yelpApiCli);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(YelpAPI.picture).into(holder.yelpPicture);
    holder.textName.setText(YelpAPI.name);
    holder.textRating.setText(YelpAPI.rating);
    holder.textReviews.setText(YelpAPI.reviews);
    holder.textAddressDetails.setText(YelpAPI.fullAddress);
    holder.textInfo.setText(YelpAPI.moreInfo);
    holder.textID.setText(YelpAPI.businessID);
```

---------- First...

```
    if(position == 0){
        firstBusiness = YelpAPI.businessID; //these three String variables get created above
    } else if(position == 1){
        secondBusiness = YelpAPI.businessID;
    } else if (position == 2) {
        thirdBusiness = YelpAPI.businessID;
    }

    holder.business.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

----------Second...

```
            int specific = holder.getPosition();
```

----------Last...

```
            String saveMe = "";
            if(specific == 0){
                saveMe = firstBusiness;
            } else if(specific == 1){
                saveMe = secondBusiness;
            } else if(specific == 2){
                saveMe = thirdBusiness;
            }
            Log.d("Clicked this item: ", String.valueOf(specific));`
```